# Get invoice number from a WooCommerce order

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to export WooCommerce orders to my CRM. I was able to get line items, quantity and prices, but I miss invoice number.

```
function custom_woocommerce_complete_order_crm( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( !$order_id )
    return;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $order_items = $order->get_items();

    foreach( $order_items as $product ) {
        $product_name[] = $product['name']; 
        $product_qty[] = $product['qty']; 
    }

...
```

var_dump does not helped me and the WooCommerce documentation does not say anything about invoices.

Answer (score 1):

```
$invoice number = $order->get_order_number();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any function on woocommerce to have subquential order numbers, you can just get the post ID.

something like:

```
$orderid = get_the_id();
```

And by invoice number, do you mean the order id?

Hope this helps!

Comment: No I mean the invoice id.

Comment: are you using another plugin to add invoice id?

Comment: No. Invoicing is a standard feature of WooCommerce

Comment: I can tell you right now that invoicing is NOT a standard feature. Maybe thats why you cannot find any documentation about it over at woothemes.

Comment: @danyo there's invoice number or ID in WooCommerce... This depends on the payment gateway.. example, in Paypal, it is by default `WC-{order_id}`.. and you can set the `WC-` in checkout settings, under Paypal gateway..

Comment: You're right, in my case I'm using PDF Invoices and Packing Slips. I'm having troubles in understanding how to programmatically get the invoice number. I tried to `var_dump($order);` but public properties aren't shown